# bitbucketに公開鍵を設定したのにpush時にパスワードを求められる

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh

bitbucketに公開鍵を設定したのですがpush時にパスワードを求められてしまいます。パスワードを省略するにはどのようにしたら良いでしょうか？鍵にパスフレーズは設定していません。

Comment: 最近opensslを新しくしませんでしたか？ 秘密鍵のパーミッションが正しく設定されていないとエラーが出るかもしれません。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SSH**ではなく**HTTPS**でクローンしていませんか？`remote`を確認してみてください。

### remoteの確認

remoteの確認：

```
$ cat .git/config
```

例えば、`.git/config`のurlがhttpsから始まっているのであればHTTPSでクローンしています。

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://user@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/therepo.git
```

HTTPSでクローンしている場合は以下の画像のようにHTTPSからSSHに変更してクローンをするためのURLを取得してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### remoteの変更方法

```
$ git remote set-url origin SSL_URL
```

例：

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/therepo.git
```

#### 参照リンク

- [Git on Bitbucket: Always asked for password, even after uploading my public SSH key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600652/git-on-bitbucket-always-asked-for-password-even-after-uploading-my-public-ssh)
- [Push updates to a repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Push+updates+to+a+repo)

Answer (score 1):

`https:` のURLが登録されているのでは？
`git@bitbucket.org:` であれば聞かれないと思います。

```
git remote -v
```

でリモートのURLを確認してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

もし、上記のような状態であれば、下記のコマンドでURLを変更できます。

```
$ git remote set-url origin [SSH_url]
```